# My TFS is not prompting for Merges/ Code differences, simply overwriting? Are there any TFS settings?

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I got the latest code for my database project. When i check in my stored proc, It **simply overwrote** the TFS version and it **didn't even prompt** for any Merges or differences.

Wondering if there are settings that i have to take care?

Comment: No, there are no settings, and TFS is agnostic about the data being stored (.NET versus database projects.)  Could you describe your workflow a bit more, and why you expect to have a conflict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TFS will only prompt for merges if someone has checked in (modified) the item after your check out. If the item hasn't changed since your check out, your check in will simply put your version in place over the existing version.  That is expected behavior.

Comment: Hmm... But can we make it to prompt? Looks like it is not prompting only for database project. But in .NET code, i believe it is prompting.

Comment: @Rita Why would you want it to prompt if there are no conflicts to merge? If your changes are the only ones made what would it need to compare? I suspect you just have other people checking in code more often than db projects so there's typically a conflict.  You should only see this code or db if someone else has checked in the code between when you checked it out and when you go to check it in.